# $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod p$ if $x^2 \equiv a \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

$p$ is an odd prime number. Show that if the equation $x^2 \equiv a \pmod p$ has no solution, then $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1 \pmod p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x^{2} \equiv a \mod p$ has no solutions, consider all $i$ and $j$ with $$ij \equiv a \mod p$$ $i$ and $j$ will not be the same as $x^{2} \equiv a \mod p$ has no solutions. Since every non-zero element is invertible in $Z_p$, the pairs exhaust all residue classes modulo $p$. Take the product of all such pairs and we will get $a^{(p-1)/2} \equiv (p-1)! \mod p$. This is congruent -1 by Wilson's theorem. Proved!